# casting a string from xml to class object

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I want to cast a string from xml file to be casted to ContactPersonType

See for loop for where string needs to be casted

```
public class ContactPersonType
{
    private String _id;
    public String ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private String _name;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

//ContactPerson class

```
private ContactPersonType _jobRole;
        public ContactPersonType JobRole
        {
            get { return _jobRole; }
            set { _jobRole = value; }
        }


public static ObservableCollection<ContactPerson> getContactPerson()
        {
            ObservableCollection<ContactPerson> ContactPersons = new ObservableCollection<ContactPerson>();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("contactpersoon.xml");

            XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("contact");
            for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
                 //this needs to be casted to ContactPersonType
                contactPerson.JobRole = elemList[i]["jobrole"].InnerText;
            }
            return ContactPersons;
        }
```

Comment: You cannot "cast" that. Look up xml serialization, there are good classes for it in the .NET Framework.

Comment: What should be the ID and what should be the Name of the new ContactPersonType? It might help to show a fragment of the relevant source XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really familliar with the way you read the XML elements so this code might need some tweaking but this should be along the lines of what you're looking for (also took the liberty of making your properties autoimplemented for higher code readability)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Program
{
    public class ContactPersonType
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContactPerson
    {
        public ContactPersonType JobRole { get; set; }

        public static ObservableCollection<ContactPerson> GetContactPerson()
        {
            var contactPersons = new ObservableCollection<ContactPerson>();
            XElement doc = XElement.Load("contactpersoon.xml");
            var contacts = doc.Elements("contact");

            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.Count(); i++)
            {
                contactPersons.Add(new ContactPerson
                {
                    JobRole = new ContactPersonType
                    {
                        ID = i.ToString(),
                        Name = contacts.ElementAt(i).Element("jobrole").Value
                    }
                });
            }

            return contactPersons;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on how you set the ID property you could possibly rewrite the loop as a foreach. For more info on XElement and it's members, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688087.aspx

Comment: this method works almost, i get a collection. 
when in the toString method i place JobRole.Name, it doesn't work.
i still get the collection

Comment: Great! Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Also feel free to post any corrections needed to make the answer work if there was any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not deserialize the XML to the .NET class with a helper such as the one shown below?

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {           
                XmlSerializer sx = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); //or T.GetType?
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
                var data = sx.Deserialize(sr);
                sr.Close();

                return (T)data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

I hate XmlDocument, so always deserialize where possible (though a potential alternative to i do like is [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

EDIT - the usage would be something like:

```
var item = Deserialize<ContactPersonType>(fileName);
```